# How to 'pause' a question?

Tags: support

I have posted a question on ask ubuntu. Now I'm on a trip and don't have access to my laptop (it is a desktop replacement and so I left it at home). Everyone's asking me to post info about the kernel panic and my laptop is left at home. I want to somehow pause this question until I reach home, open my laptop, and take a snapshot. 3 people put it on hold so is that the same thing as 'pausing' the question?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/517249/not-running-on-intel-cpu

Comment: It's on hold now. Courtesy of the best moderators on the planet. When you get back, simply edit the question to fit better here and we will help you!